# Need to configure Nortel SR1004 router for new Internet Connection

Tags: networking, router, isp, wide-area-network, nortel

I'm trying to prep for a new fiber circuit that is being installed in our office and I'm having difficulty finding much documentation on the Nortel SR1004 router.

The router currently is used for 3 bonded T1 connections that go out over the FE0 port to our firewall. I'd still like for traffic to go out over FE0 to our firewall, however I need to make use of FE1 to carry the internet from our ISP's handoff box to the router itself.

FE1 needs to be configured as such:

```
ip address w.x.y.z 255.255.255.252
vlan 3
speed 100
duplex_full
```

Additionally, there will need to be a static route configured for all internal traffic to map to w.x.y.z2.

If the router was a Cisco device, it'd be something along the lines of the below:

```
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
Description to WAN-Verizon
ip address w.x.y.z 255.255.255.252 speed 100 duplex full !
interface FastEthernet0/1
Description to LAN-Firewall
ip address a.b.c.d 255.255.255.224 speed auto !
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 FastEthernet0/0 w.x.y.z !
```

a.b.c.d = firewall IP
w.x.y.z = WAN IP for the Nortel SR1004 router
w.x.y.z2 = IP on the ISP side

If somebody could please assist with how to go about setting up the router I would greatly appreciate it. I haven't had much luck finding much information on Nortel routers at all on the internet.

Thanks in advance.

***Note:*** I figured I should also mention that once the new circuit is in place, we will no longer have any need for the T1s so I may need to know how to deactivate those ports as well (although simply unplugging them would do the trick as well possibly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nortel's enterprise solutions business was sold to Avaya when they went bankrupt. Take a look at the Avaya Secure Router 1000 Series documentation.